# how to load a pdf file in page view based application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I want to load a pdf file in a page view based application and view it like a book kind with curl transition as page view based application provide page curl transition.

so how can i achieve it  can anyone tel me with sample code which i should use in page view based application.

Comment: what have you tried so far? You can use the `UIPageViewController` data source to return a view controller subclass that controls a UIWebView, for example, in which you could load pdf content.

Comment: @alanduncan i dont wan to load in UIwebView i just want to load pdf file in Page based application.I have loaded a pdf file it works.But problem is Transition is not happening in the centre.when i swipe it swipe whole page from one end to another end.Where the flipping is not happening in the centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many option to achieve this kind of project, the fatest way is to use an open-source project, there is a lot of open-soruce project out there, here is a list of project I've found before:

- [PaperStack](https://github.com/lomanf/PaperStack)
- [PageCurlDemo](https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/PageCurlDemo)
- [leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves)